# Turtle graphics - Bullet stops when another one is created and continues once the new one ends

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
def player_bullet():
barrel = -300
bullet = turtle.Turtle()
bullet.penup()
bullet.setposition(starting_x, barrel)
bullet.color("red")
bullet.shape("triangle")
bullet.setheading(90)

bullet.shapesize(0.5, 0.5)
while True:
    if barrel > 300:
        bullet.ht()
        break
    barrel += 10
    bullet.sety(barrel)
    turtle.update()

while True:
    turtle.onkeypress(move_left, key="Left")
    turtle.onkeypress(move_right, key="Right")
    turtle.onkeypress(player_bullet, key="space")
    turtle.listen()
    turtle.update()
```

*the bullet shoots and stops once another bullet is created and shot...I want the first bullet to finish it's run while being able to create new bullets.* This is for a space invaders game with turtle graphics.

Comment: The pasted code probably does not have the indentation of your actual code.

Comment: aside from indentation, there are undefined variables:  `starting_x`, `move_left`, `move_right`...  so where are those comming from please ?

Comment: Sorry about the indentation...the first while loop should be indented.
The undefined variables are there I just didn't add them to the code pasted.

Comment: You can [edit] your post to fix the problems.

Comment: You'll probably want a list to keep track of the bullets. See [this code example](https://github.com/HaimingXu679/Asteroids/blob/master/bullet.py).